# my kubernetes service not connect to rabbitmq on docker container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rabbitmq

I'm developing a simple microservice application using kubernetes. I use skaffold for development and production. And I provide communication between my services with rabbitmq.

When I run my kubernetes services locally (i.e. manually without kubernetes) I can connect to my docker container. But when I run my apps through kubernetes I can't connect to my docker container.

The url I use when I try it manually is:
`BROKER_URI=amqp://127.0.0.1:15672`

As I said above url works manually but not with kubernetes. It would also be illogical for it to work because its url is 127.0.0.1. So I wrote a rabbitmq kubernetes service like below.

The url I use when I try it kubernetes is:
`amqp:://backend-rabbitmq-srv:5672`

// backend-rabbitmq-srv.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-rabbitmq-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend-rabbitmq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend-rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: backend-rabbitmq
          image: rabbitmq:3
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-rabbitmq-srv
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: backend-rabbitmq
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 15672
      targetPort: 15672
      nodePort: 31672
    - name: amqp
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5672
      targetPort: 5672
      nodePort: 30672
```

However, I am still getting an error as below. Where could I be missing?

The error:

```
[is-chat] OperationalError: connect ECONNREFUSED                 
10.104.248.71:5672
[is-chat]     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]     (node:net:1195:16) {
[is-chat]   cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.104.248.71:5672
[is-chat]       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1195:16) {
[is-chat]     errno: -111,
[is-chat]     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
[is-chat]     syscall: 'connect',
[is-chat]     address: '10.104.248.71',
[is-chat]     port: 5672
[is-chat]   },
[is-chat]   isOperational: true,
[is-chat]   errno: -111,
[is-chat]   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
[is-chat]   syscall: 'connect',
[is-chat]   address: '10.104.248.71',
[is-chat]   port: 5672
[is-chat] }
```

Comment: You seem to have included a PNG file of some sort in place of the error message.  Can you [edit] the question to fix this?  Can you tell if the RabbitMQ Pod is starting up?  Is the client also running in a Kubernetes Pod, or somewhere else?

Comment: I added the error message as code. Kubernetes service works in partnership with microservices. I think the error may be that my other services are created before rabbitmq is created yet. I'll give this a try.

Comment: Have you double-checked that `kubectl describe service backend-rabbitmq-srv` shows `Endpoints:` connected to the Pod?  Does `kubectl logs deployment/backend-rabbitmq-depl` suggest RabbitMQ is in fact starting?  Is your client in a different Pod in the same Namespace?

Comment: `kubectl logs deployment/backend-rabbitmq-depl` this code shows rabbitmq is running. There is nothing wrong. `kubectl describe service backend-rabbitmq-srv` according to this code my endpoint is `172.17.0.10:15672`. but when i run this code i get timeout error: `telnet 172.17.0.10 15672`.  normally this was not out of service. I've made it external for testing right now. But I am not getting results from rabbitmq

Comment: Your error message has a different IP address 10.104.248.71, where does that come from?

Comment: 172.17.0.10 is `backend-rabbitmq-srv`'s endpoint IP. `backend-rabbitmq-srv`'s Ip is 10.104.248.71. ip address and endpoint address look different